# How do you use orderBy when calling a Firestore Collection?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the [Firestore documentation][1]. The query returns data if I leave out the `.orderBy` but when I include it, there is no data.

```
async getAccounts() {
   return await this.db
    .collection("mas-accounts")
    .get()
    .orderBy("names.givenName")
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        doc = doc.data();
        console.log(doc);
      });
    });
}
```

A sample of results without order by:

> names: {familyName: "Doe", givenName: "John"}
>   relations: {person: "Junior Blanks", type: "child"}

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added a picture.

Comment: What is the exact line of code that you are using when ordering with `orderBy`? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo.  ouch. I cannot believe I left that out.

Comment: Have you tried to add `.orderBy("names.givenName")` before get()?

Comment: that was it. Please post as answer.

Comment: you would think i'd get an error in the console.

Comment: So adding `.orderBy("names.givenName")` before `get()` solved your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187422/discussion-between-greg-harner-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> the vs code emmet gives a .orderBy option on .get() and on .collection() and the console does not give an error it just returns an empty promise.

The solution for solving this problem is to add a call to `.orderBy("names.givenName")` function before calling `get()`.